# How to fill empty cells of a csv file with 0 and remove cells where there is no header?

Tags: scripting

I want to import a really disgusting csv file with empty cells and cells without headers to Cassandra database. I tried

The following command from [linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fill-all-empty-valued-cells-within-a-csv-file-with-sed-and-bash-shell) :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( seq 1 2); do
  sed -e "s/^,/$2,/" -e "s/,,/,$2,/g" -e "s/,$/,$2/" -i $1
done
```

But it didn't seemed to work when I applied it to

```
bash fill-empty-values.sh bouffe500.csv 0
```

I didn't `chmod +x` it .

Here is an image of bouffe500.csv after applying it script, it remains empty fields :

[image: image of bouffe500.csv after applying it script, it remains empty fields]

---

I thought the empty fields created problems when I tried to import the csv file into Cassandra and it answered me :

```
cqlsh:k1> COPY k1.bouffe FROM 'bouffe_v2.csv' WITH HEADER=true;
Using 3 child processes

Starting copy of k1.bouffe with columns [code, additives, additives_fr, ...
...
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 112 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 7 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 60 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 74 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 2 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 32 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 5 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 31 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 85 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 111 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to import 3 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 81 should be 163,  given up without retries
Failed to process 499 rows; failed rows written to import_k1_bouffe.err
Processed: 499 rows; Rate:     801 rows/s; Avg. rate:    1211 rows/s
499 rows imported from 1 files in 0.412 seconds (0 skipped).
cqlsh:k1> SELECT * from bouffe;
```

Comment: why `$( seq 1 2)` ?

Comment: Their `sed` command requires two passes over the input file.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest You're right I think there is a problem here. I think the guy from linuxconfig.org use `seq 1 2` because the guy gives an example with numbers only

Comment: The script works fine (as long as it's GNU `sed` with support for `-i`). Have you viewed the output in a text editor rather than spreadsheet?

Comment: @BLayer No, only on LibreOffice Calc

Comment: What about now? :P

Comment: @BLayer
Hard to tell because it's hard to a `cat bouffe.csv` with at least 150 columns and 50 rows. Furthermore I still have the same errors when importing it to Cassandra

Comment: View it in `vim`. Or just grep for `,,`. If you don't get any results then the file is probably the way you wanted it to be....in which case perhaps your spreadsheet doesn't like plain `0` in a cell...or perhaps it's fine with `0` but it renders it as blank. (I'm not even addressing Cassandra right now just the first part of your question.)